# Why is the estimated result of AUC in roc.test() inconsistent with the original result?

Tags: roc, auc, proc-r-package

I made two ROC curves and one of the results is as follows:

```
> roc1 <- roc(cData$`<60`$resule, cData$`<60`$SOFA1)
Setting levels: control = survival, case = death
Setting direction: controls <cases
> roc1

Call:
roc.default(response = cData$`<60`$resule, predictor = cData$`<60`$SOFA1)

Data: cData$`<60`$SOFA1 in 26 controls (cData$`<60`$resule survival) <18 cases (cData$`<60`$resule death).
Area under the curve: 0.7692
```

Another result is as follows:

```
    > roc2 <- roc(cData$`<60`$resule, cData$`<60`$SOFA7)
    Setting levels: control = survival, case = death
    Setting direction: controls <cases
    > roc2



Call:
roc.default(response = cData$`<60`$resule, predictor = cData$`<60`$SOFA7)

Data: cData$`<60`$SOFA7 in 26 controls (cData$`<60`$resule survival) <2 cases (cData$`<60`$resule death).
Area under the curve: 0.9327
```

The result obtained after comparing through the `roc.test()` of the `pROC` package is:

```
> roc.test(roc1,roc2)

DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves

data: roc1 and roc2
Z = 0.54339, p-value = 0.5869
alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
AUC of roc1 AUC of roc2
  0.9615385 0.9326923
```

The AUC of roc1 was 0.7692 and the AUC of roc2 was 0.9327, but why after comparing with `roc.test()`, the AUC becomes 0.9615385 0.9326923 respectively?

Comment: Please add an minimal reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/333599 on how to do that.

Comment: I think I found the reason for the inconsistent results. The reason is that my data has missing values. The number of missing values in different indicators is different. In `roc.test()`, all indicators will be merged and the missing values will be deleted, which leads to the final results are inconsistent. I did it again in MedCalc, and got the same result in R. Thank you Calimo.